# Angular 5 : app-root component not loading after switching to XAMPP

Tags: angular, xampp

> EDIT
>    A kind person helped me to find a another way to do. BUT if someone can explain why my Angular project only display a blank page on the browser i'm still taking it. Do Xampp needs something to read Angular ?

**Context :**

I'm currently doing a project on Angular 5. Until now i was using the ng serve command in Webstorm IDE to create my server and display it. Everything was working well.

Then to be able to display the backend PHP part i switch to xampp. 
I simply put my project in the "htdocs directory" of XAMPP and then ran the npm start command. The project compile perfectly and i get no errors.

**Issue :**

But, but, when i display in the browser the localhost address, i got a **blank page**, no html. If i write something in my app-root tag, it display it.
Of course there are no errors, that would be too simple.
There were similar issues in StackOverflow but not without errors, and not with the same environment.

**Question :**

I guess that there is an issue with maybe the loading of my modules and maybe the config files. But since i'm pretty new to Angular, i don't know where to dig to allow that. I have been searching some answers all over the internet, but nothing came up.

Is there anyone having any idea where to look for ?

I'll be very grateful.
I'll show you more of my files, but for now i don't know what should be useful to put.

Thank you

**My index.html file :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CRAPO</title>
  <base href="/Crapo/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Chargement ...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "I simply put my project in the "htdocs directory"" mean exactly.

Comment: I took the folder created with the angular-cli command ng new PROJECT-NAME and transfered it in htdocs

Comment: Ok, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the project https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build and put the content of the `dist/` folder into the `htdocs` folder

Comment: ok Thank you @Günter Zöchbauer, i'll try that. But i don't want yet to be in production. Is it fine to use build already and still do as i was in dev ?

Comment: The link I posted shows how to build for development and production. If you want do use the XAMPP server for development together with `ng serve` something like https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/ might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, it might be what i was looking for !